# Как в БД phpmyadmin сохранить много картинок под слайдер?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Как в БД phpmyadmin сохранить множество картинок для слайдер

Answer (score 2):

Тип varchar и ссылка на картинку + вызывать в `<img src=<?php echo ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ С ССЫЛКОЙ НА КАРТИНКУ ?>>`. Не вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется ввиду один ко многим: одна статья/новость в свой таблице а к ней много картинок, то делаете вторую таблицу для картинок. Поля id, item_id, image_url
В поле item_id пишите id статьи и делаете столько строк сколько нужно картинок и после гуглите sql join для связывания таблиц.